# How can I ensure that Locust counts accurate requests

Tags: python, testing, locust

I used Master-Worker mode with 4 workers in total

I implemented a way to count the number of jobs executed. When I hit the Stop button in WebUI and the test ended, the number of requests counted by Locust deviated from the number of jobs executed by me. And in the target servers tested, I found that the actual number of requests received by the target server also deviated from the number of requests made by Locust

The following code implements count += 1 every time the task is executed

```py
import copy
from locust import events, FastHttpUser, task, constant_throughput
from locust.runners import MasterRunner
from src import utils
from src.common import ApiClass
from src.common.msg import ResponseMsg
from src.common.handle import AccountBase

req_count = 0


class CommentTask(FastHttpUser, AccountBase):
    wait_time = constant_throughput(1)

    def __init__(self, environment):
        super().__init__(environment)
        self.header = copy.deepcopy(ApiClass.Header)

    @staticmethod
    def on_count(msg, **_kwargs):
        global req_count
        req_count += msg.data['count']

    @staticmethod
    @events.init.add_listener
    def on_locust_init(environment, **_kwargs):
        AccountBase.on_locust_init(environment, **_kwargs)
        CommentTask.host = ApiClass.Host
        if isinstance(environment.runner, MasterRunner):
            environment.runner.register_message('on_count', CommentTask.on_count)

    @staticmethod
    @events.test_start.add_listener
    def on_test_start(environment, **_kwargs):
        AccountBase.on_test_start(environment, **_kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    @events.test_stop.add_listener
    def on_test_stop(environment):
        if isinstance(environment.runner, MasterRunner):
            global req_count
            utils.Log.info(req_count)

    def on_start(self):
        self.header['Token'] = self.account.get()['token']

    @task
    def do_comment(self):
        self.environment.runner.send_message('on_count', {'count': 1})
        with self.client.post(url=ApiClass.Path.CommentSave, headers=self.header, json={},
                              catch_response=True) as response:
            ResponseMsg.assert_send(self.environment.runner, response)
```

After I hit the Stop button in WebUI, I counted the number of counts myself

```
[INFO]-[2023-08-23 11:16:21]-[Dummy-3:2179754179648]-[comment.py:86] - 1728
```

[Statistics displayed on the WebUI page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdxNM.png)

The actual number of requests received by the target server under test is 1725

How can I make sure that Locust is counting an accurate number of requests when there are no other requests

Comment: What do you get if you send the count message after the request? Do you then get a count higher than what Locust reports for requests?

Comment: @Solowalker The counter is +1 before the request is sent, which proves that Locust executed the task. My counter actually got 1728, but the number of requests given by Locust was 1712, and the actual number of requests received by the target server under test was 1725, which makes me confused

Comment: That's why I'm asking what happens if you increment the counter after the request. When you're stopping the test, there's no guarantee where a Locust user is in the task you defined. Your task 1) increments count 2) sends request 3) reports request to Locust so it can update its own stats. Moving your increment would show you the behavior and I would then expect your custom increment to be the lowest.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the -s/--stop-timeout setting. That will allow task iterations to finish within a set time instead of aborting immediately.